# MySQL Performance - string vs integer

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, mysql-workbench

I have realized a very strange behavior of MySQL that I have no explanation for.

This is a not overly complex query:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  incidents.incidents AS inc, 
  incidents.enrichment AS enr 
WHERE 
  inc.Id <= 606734 
  AND inc.Id >= 1 
  AND inc.Id = enr.ParentTableId 
  AND (
    enr.Enricher3State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher4State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher5State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher9State = 2
  );
```

The columns Enricher3State, Enricher4State, Enricher5State, Enricher9State do have an index and are of the datatype int(11).

Now I have tried to change these Enricher[x]State to a string:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  incidents.incidents AS inc, 
  incidents.enrichment AS enr 
WHERE 
  inc.Id <= 606734 
  AND inc.Id >= 1 
  AND inc.Id = enr.ParentTableId 
  AND (
    enr.Enricher3State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher4State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher5State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher9State = '2'
  );
```

Every common sense would say that the string variant should perform the same, or slower, because the datatype of the column is integer!

But apparently this is not the case!

Query with integer notation (first one): 7.23048825s

Query with string notation (last one): 5.22188450s

As you can see, there is a huge performance difference, even though the query cost is the same in both cases.

I have absolutely no clue how this difference could happen - and if this means, I should change all queries in my project using the string notation...

I am using MySQL version 5.7.10

---

According to your comments I have deactivated all services that write or read to the database and repeated the experiment.

A) The integer notation:

```
SET profiling=0;
SET profiling=1;

SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  incidents.incidents AS inc, 
  incidents.enrichment AS enr 
WHERE 
  inc.Id <= 606734 
  AND inc.Id >= 1 
  AND inc.Id = enr.ParentTableId 
  AND (
    enr.Enricher3State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher4State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher5State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher9State = 2
  );

SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  incidents.incidents AS inc, 
  incidents.enrichment AS enr 
WHERE 
  inc.Id <= 606734 
  AND inc.Id >= 1 
  AND inc.Id = enr.ParentTableId 
  AND (
    enr.Enricher3State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher4State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher5State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher9State = 2
  );

SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  incidents.incidents AS inc, 
  incidents.enrichment AS enr 
WHERE 
  inc.Id <= 606734 
  AND inc.Id >= 1 
  AND inc.Id = enr.ParentTableId 
  AND (
    enr.Enricher3State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher4State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher5State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher9State = 2
  );

SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  incidents.incidents AS inc, 
  incidents.enrichment AS enr 
WHERE 
  inc.Id <= 606734 
  AND inc.Id >= 1 
  AND inc.Id = enr.ParentTableId 
  AND (
    enr.Enricher3State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher4State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher5State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher9State = 2
  );

SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  incidents.incidents AS inc, 
  incidents.enrichment AS enr 
WHERE 
  inc.Id <= 606734 
  AND inc.Id >= 1 
  AND inc.Id = enr.ParentTableId 
  AND (
    enr.Enricher3State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher4State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher5State = 2 
    OR enr.Enricher9State = 2
  );

  SHOW PROFILES;
```

Execution time of each query:

- 6.42429325
- 5.95059900
- 6.34392825
- 6.53041775
- 6.69593450

B) The string notation:

```
SET profiling=0;
SET profiling=1;

SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  incidents.incidents AS inc, 
  incidents.enrichment AS enr 
WHERE 
  inc.Id <= 606734 
  AND inc.Id >= 1 
  AND inc.Id = enr.ParentTableId 
  AND (
    enr.Enricher3State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher4State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher5State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher9State = '2'
  );

SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  incidents.incidents AS inc, 
  incidents.enrichment AS enr 
WHERE 
  inc.Id <= 606734 
  AND inc.Id >= 1 
  AND inc.Id = enr.ParentTableId 
  AND (
    enr.Enricher3State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher4State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher5State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher9State = '2'
  );

SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  incidents.incidents AS inc, 
  incidents.enrichment AS enr 
WHERE 
  inc.Id <= 606734 
  AND inc.Id >= 1 
  AND inc.Id = enr.ParentTableId 
  AND (
    enr.Enricher3State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher4State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher5State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher9State = '2'
  );

SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  incidents.incidents AS inc, 
  incidents.enrichment AS enr 
WHERE 
  inc.Id <= 606734 
  AND inc.Id >= 1 
  AND inc.Id = enr.ParentTableId 
  AND (
    enr.Enricher3State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher4State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher5State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher9State = '2'
  );

SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  incidents.incidents AS inc, 
  incidents.enrichment AS enr 
WHERE 
  inc.Id <= 606734 
  AND inc.Id >= 1 
  AND inc.Id = enr.ParentTableId 
  AND (
    enr.Enricher3State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher4State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher5State = '2' 
    OR enr.Enricher9State = '2'
  );

  SHOW PROFILES;
```

Execution time:

- 5.07188875
- 4.90356250
- 4.86164300
- 4.48403375
- 5.06533725

As you can clearly see, the string notation is still faster!

The same behavior was also detected by other developers of my team, so I could exclude temporary stupidity of myself…

Comment: Likely the InnoDB buffer cache at work. Try again, this time running each query twice in a row. Discard the first result, report the second result of each query. That is, run integer query, integer query (report this one), string query, string query (report this one.) Also, if the results still vary, up to 4 each, discard the first still, and then average the remaining 3 for each query.

Comment: Also there should be no other activity on the database, to really be comparing apples to apples.

Comment: I have modified the test according to your input - but the result is still the same.

Comment: What does it say when you type EXPLAIN in front of your query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the fields are indexed and you have OR condition and query does have integer constant as the condition, MySQL may spend time on cross index join calculation and then do table scan and with string constant MySQL does not do index considerations and just does table scan.

It is the case when having indices on many fields that are used in OR condition is not advantage but extra work for MySQL.

The OR condition does not grant required indexing of participating fields, quite often having indices on the "1,2,3,4" fields is bad for the table. These fields should be taken out to a separate table.

Added: Run EXPLAIN and if you see indices "1,2,3,4" fields listed for considered keys, that is what MySQL is spending the time on.

Answer (score 4):

Considering the answer from Sergiy Tytarenko, I have deleted the indices on the Enricher[x]State columns.

Execution time for integer notation:

- 4.93739900
- 5.01461550
- 5.05932075
- 5.02891175
- 5.02525075

Execution time for string notation:

- 5.04365650
- 5.07545950
- 5.12358825
- 5.14665200
- 5.15426525

The execution time is about the same now.

So indeed, when having multiple indices on columns connected with OR, care should be taken.

It seems I have accidentally discovered a nice workaround (except deleting the index), by making a string out of an integer...

Comment: Yes, it is a nice workaround, but you have to rely on developers to follow it, and your framework to allow use quotes when preparing the queries. In other cases (like a single condition or conditions with AND) using quotes for integer constant will be a big hurt. Considering common reasons to "1,2,3,4" fields on the table, these should not be indexed (and often you cannot just remodel table to avoid using them).

Comment: Personally, I would try writing the query differently, avoiding `OR`'ing the predicates, because the MySQL optimizer tends not to generate optimal execution plans for queries that have `OR`'d predicates.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've executed each of the queries multiple times, and thrown out the results from the first execution, we do see a significant difference in 
average execution time.

The performance difference is likely due to a difference in the execution plan.

I would take a close look at the output from EXPLAIN EXTENDED on both queries. Very likely that the execution plans are different in some way (which indexes are being used, the order of operations, etc.)

My observations... MySQL query optimizer and queries with `OR` conditions... the query plans are not optimal. To get better performance, I usually resort to breaking the query up and using UNION ALL set operations.

For getting a "count", I would be apt to write the query like this:

```
  SELECT SUM(2 IN (enr.enricher3state,
                   enr.enricher4state,
                   enr.enricher5state,
                   enr.enricher9state))
    FROM incidents.incidents inc
    JOIN incidents.enrichment enr 
      ON enr.parenttableid = inc.id
   WHERE inc.id <= 606734 
     AND inc.id >= 1
```

I'd be sure to have a covering index available, e.g.

```
ON enrichment (parenttableid, enricher3state, enricher4state,
                              enricher5state, enricher9state)
```

(or any index with parenttableid as the leading column, which also includes the other four columns)

Then I'd check the EXPLAIN EXTENDED output and performance.

Answer (score 0):

**Comparison to numbers**

```
char = 123   -- slow because it converts the char to numeric; can't use index
char = '123' -- fine
int = 123    -- fine
int = '123'  -- fine - because '123' is converted to numeric up front
```

Bottom line:  It is always safe to quote constants.

**OR**

`OR` is essentially un-optimizable.  However, the following may have the same effect, but faster...

A general rule in **schema design**:  "Do not splay an array of things across columns."  Instead, make another table and set up a 1:many relationship between them.  This *may* be the best solution for performance.

Please use **`JOIN ... ON ...`** syntax, not the 'commajoin'.

**Profiling**

5.6.7 says "The SHOW PROFILE and SHOW PROFILES statements. Use the Performance Schema instead; see MySQL Performance Schema."

**Indexing**

It is rare for an index to be useful on a low-cardinality column, such as what I expect Enricher3State is.

**IN vs OR**

`2 IN (...)` versus `..=2 OR ..=2 OR...` -- these probably don't make much difference.  No index can be used; both involve some complexity.

**More info**

Need to see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.
Need to see `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.